# Growl loads in dialog box by default

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces dialog box and inside it have a input text area. The text area is a required field. When the button is clicked, I get the growl message. But even when the dialog box opens up for the first time, I still do get the growl message. Where am I wrong?

```
<p:dialog id="dumpNotesDialog" >
<p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" id="message" />
<p:inputTextarea required="true" requiredMessage="Enter notes to save" id="dumpnotes" value="#{postProcessedDump.keyedinContent}" />
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{dumpController.saveDumpNotesContent}" update="message" />
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: could you please post the code from where you open this Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you should be form in dialog like below code

```
<h:body>
        <h:form id="formId">
            <p:commandButton value="test" onclick="PF('dlg').show()" />

        </h:form>
        <p:dialog id="dumpNotesDialog"  widgetVar="dlg" appendTo="@(body)">
            <h:form>
                <p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" id="message" />
                <p:inputTextarea required="true" requiredMessage="Enter notes to save" id="dumpnotes" />
                <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{dumpController.saveDumpNotesContent}" update="message" /> 
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
```

Comment: Why 'should' that be? Please explain so it is clear why it might be needed?

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog is probably located in the same form as the button that opens it. And the opening button needlessly submits the form (needlessly, if it doesn't do anything but open the dialog).

To fix make separate forms for the opening button and the dialog. The dialog form is usually inside the dialog. Add `type="button"` to the `p:commandButton` that opens the dialog so that it doesn't make an unnecessary POST request.

Comment: _"Your dialog is **probably** located in the same form"_: better to ask for clarification in a comment first before answering

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I wrote a little example for you. We do not know your ManagedBean code because of this I suppose a simple Java code for this example.
The view only has a button to show the dialog and inside it has a input text area and a button called Save for calling the method of ManagedBean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <h:head>  
            <title>Test Primefaces</title>
        </h:head>  

        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Open" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
                <p:dialog id="dumpNotesDialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
                    <p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" id="message" />
                    <p:inputTextarea required="true" requiredMessage="Enter notes to save" id="dumpnotes" value="#{dumpController.message}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{dumpController.saveDumpNotesContent}" update="message" />
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>  
    </html>
```

The ManagedBean code has an object for binding the textarea field and a method which is calling when the Save button is pressed.

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean
public class DumpController {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void saveDumpNotesContent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        /*TODO Your opearations here!*/

        final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful",  "Your message: " + message) );
    }
}
```

Please, include your Java code if you want a better answer.

Comment: I fail to understand the problem of the OP (might be my limitation) and I fail to understand what your answer solves (what is different then what the OP does). It is always better to make sure the question is ok and clear before answering.